# Angularjs nested json object with ng-repeat not working at ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

First of all, I'm pretty new to the ionic and angularjs. Now I trying to develop a app and i'm having trouble displaying and searching data right now.

I have a nested json object and I cannot display it with ng-repeat.

Here is the json object.

```
$scope.nestedTestdata = [{
                "leadlist ": [{
                    "submitted_date": "01-01-2160",
                    "submission_value": {
                        "full_name": "Full Name ",
                        "phone": "This is test data.",
                        "source": "I hate you"
                    }
                },
                    {
                        "submitted_date": "01-01-2015",
                        "submission_value": {
                            "full_name": "full name",
                            "phone": "phone.",
                            "source": "I really really hate you"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "submitted_date": "01-01-2016",
                        "submission_value": {
                            "full_name": "I am awesome",
                            "phone": "HP phone.",
                            "source": "I hate you"
                        }
                    }]
            }];
```

Here is how I display.

```
 <div class="lead_row" ng-repeat="data in nestedTestdata.leadlist | filter: model.search" >

            <div class="lead_col">{{data.submitted_date | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.source}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.full_name}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.phone}}</div>    
        </div>
```

When I change it to following json object, it can display and search function also working.

```
 $scope.testdata = [{
                "submitted_date": "01-01-2160",
                "submission_value": {
                    "full_name": "Search is working",
                    "phone": "This is fucking test data.",
                    "source": "I hate you"
                }
            },
                {
                    "submitted_date": "01-01-2015",
                    "submission_value": {
                        "full_name": "Fucking full name",
                        "phone": "Fucking phone.",
                        "source": "I really really hate you"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "submitted_date": "01-01-2016",
                    "submission_value": {
                        "full_name": "I am awesome",
                        "phone": "Fucking HP phone.",
                        "source": "I hate you"
                    }
                }];
```

So I think it is not displaying problem. 
Please help to figure out how can i make this work.

Please check inside the following link for the full code. 
http://play.ionic.io/app/720567016712

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nestedTestData contains an array. Inside the array, there is an object.

```
ng-repeat="data in nestedTestdata[0].leadlist | filter: model.search"
```

SO code should be as follows:

```
 <div class="lead_row" ng-repeat="data in nestedTestdata[0].leadlist | filter: model.search" >
                <div class="lead_col">{{data.submitted_date | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</div>
                <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.source}}</div>
                <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.full_name}}</div>
                <div class="lead_col">{{data.submission_value.phone}}</div>    
            </div>
```

Comment: You just save my day. I totally overlook it.Thank you so much. I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array then you are defining another array with an object with a key of 'leadlist'. The answer above could solve your problem or you could just remove the array above your key you can just access it as normal `data.nestedTestData`

Below is how you could rewrite it:

```
`$scope.nestedTestdata = {
    "leadlist" : [{
        "submitted_date": "01-01-2160",
        "submission_value": {
         "full_name": "Full Name ",
         "phone": "This is test data.",
          "source": "I hate you"  
    }

},
{
    "submitted_date": "01-01-2015",
    "submission_value": {
        "full_name": "full name",
        "phone": "phone.",
        "source": "I really really hate you"
    }
},
{
    "submitted_date": "01-01-2016",
    "submission_value": {
        "full_name": "I am awesome",
        "phone": "HP phone.",
        "source": "I hate you"
    }  
}]
```

};`

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `ng-repeat`, It will also work if there are multiple objects in `$scope.nestedTestdata`.
[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/10275/)

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="lead_row" ng-repeat="data in nestedTestdata">
        <div ng-repeat="list in data.leadlist">
            <div class="lead_col">{{list.submitted_date | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{list.submission_value.source}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{list.submission_value.full_name}}</div>
            <div class="lead_col">{{list.submission_value.phone}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please remove the space after `"leadlist "`